# ListView selected index

Tags: asp.net-4.0, webforms

I have a paged multicolumn ListView of items with ImageButton and LinkButton. The delete and select commands are working. I can't get the SelectedIndexChanging event to fire, and the SelectedIndex is always -1 in the Select command handler. I think I have the required select button as per the docs. My ultimate goal is to save the index of the item so when I return to the page I can restore the current ListView pager page so the selected item is visible. But I can't get the item index. This is for asp.net 4.0 webforms.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ListView1_ItemDataBound"
  DataKeyNames="ItemID" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1"
  OnItemCommand="ListView1_ItemCommand" GroupItemCount="2" 
  onselectedindexchanging="ListView1_SelectedIndexChanging">
  <LayoutTemplate>
    <table width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table class="sample" width="100%">
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <GroupTemplate>
    <tr>
      <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </tr>
  </GroupTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <td>
      <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" ToolTip="Delete" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ItemID")%>' CommandName="DeleteItem" Height="12" ImageUrl="resources/delete.gif" Width="12" />
      <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSelect" runat="server" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ItemID")%>'><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ItemName") %></asp:LinkButton>
      <asp:Label ID="ccLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </td>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: I think I am going to try the DataPager.StartRowIndex property instead, persist it somehow for the user's return to the page.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you posted your code (SelectedIndexChanging).  But in any case, one thought:

`SelectedIndexChanging` won't give you the selected index, because the index hasn't actually been selected yet.

Use `SelectedIndexChanged` instead.  This occurs after the index has been selected, so can give you a value.

Comment: There is no code in SelectedIndexChanging for now, just a Debug.WriteLine of the NewSelectedIndex, but it doesn't fire anyway. I added a SelectedIndexChanged handler and it never fires either.

Comment: Instead of assigning the function in the mark-up (`onselectedindexchanging="ListView1_SelectedIndexChanging">`, have you tried doing it in the code-behind?  Double-click your listview, then in the code-behind that opens-up, make sure it's on 'onselectedinexchanged', and put your code in there.  It wouldn't explain why your current method isn't working, but if it works, at least the problem is solved.